# How to capture HTTP request in OWASP ZAP

Tags: zap

I need to scan some APIs that only available on HTTP protocol.

Let's say I'm testing http://example.com, I did follow commands

```
export http_proxy=localhost:8080
export https_proxy=localhost:8080
curl http://example.com  
<html><body>Redirecting to https://example.com/</body></html>
```

http://example.com is accessible however ZAP proxy always gives me a 302 Redirect response.
And in the GUI, there is nothing captured by ZAP.

Capturing HTTPS APIs is working well, but how can I make it work for HTTP?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've got the HUD enabled - that always redirect to HTTPS.
Thats explained in the tutorial that would have been linked to when you you started using ZAP.
You can turn the HUD off via a button on the toolbar or a checkbox on the relevant Quick Start tab.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have also faced an issue regarding HTTPS during manual exploration of my application using OWASP ZAP.

After disabling the Enable HUD option on Quick Start Tab, the issue got solved.

[image]

[owasp](/questions/tagged/owasp)[zap](/questions/tagged/zap)[httprequest](/questions/tagged/httprequest)