# How do I work with HTTP sites using the HUD in OWASP's Zap Proxy

Tags: owasp, zap

This is a follow-up to this question: [How to capture HTTP request in OWASP ZAP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59666603/491553)

In my case the original site uses HTTP. Zap (with the HUD turned on) annoyingly upgrades it HTTPs which works but when that site tries to access a secondary server for data it passes the HTTP header:

Origin: http**s**://example.com

This fails because that server has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com` header response (without the **s** at the end of HTTP).

In short, has anybody found a work-around to get ZAP (with HUD turned on) to stop upgrading the connection to HTTPs? This is a development site. I want all HTTPs turned off.  None of this happens in regular Chome/Firefox without ZAP as a proxy.

For other folks Googling for this issue, here is the message in Chrome that comes up that you see in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/blah' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

Comment: I think this bug is related: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud/issues/440

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! You can just replace the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the correct site to fool Chrome into thinking the CORS headers are okay.

In ZAP (not in Chrome/the HUD), go to Tools->Replacer Options:
[image: Tools->Replacer Options]

Then click `Add` to add a new Replacer Option:

- **Description:** Replace Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- **Match Regex:** unchecked
- **Match String:** Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- **Match Type:** Response Header (will add if not present)
- **Replacement String:** https://example.com
- **Enable:** checked

Like so:

[image]

Then click "Save". Now re-launch Chrome with the HUD and it should work.

Comment: Oh nice. We should probably do this automatically in ZAP. I've just raised this bug for it: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud/issues/753